# ESP8266 GPIO limitations with HC-SR04

Tags: esp8266, sensors, pins, esp32, hc-sr04

I want to build a systems that measures if some parking spots are occupied or not. I chose to use an ESP8266 12-E NodeMCU Kit with multiple HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensors. In my project, it is essential to connect as many ultrasonic sensors to one ESP. Unfortunately, I have found out that if I connect the input/output of the HCSR04 to GPIO 10/9 and GPIO 1/3, The board can't boot. Can anyone explain to me why I cannot use those GPIO pins and what alternatives I have in order to connect more sensors to the ESP (other microcontrollers, pin extenders etc.)?

Comment: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/

Comment: The ESP8266 is a very poor choice if you want to use multiple GPIOs. There are very few you can actually use. You are better off using something else. Even the ESP32 is better, though that is still somewhat picky with some GPIOs.